# What should be the connection string in .net core api to be able to connect to the dockerized sql express?

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I could download and run the `microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express`
So this is works:

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=MyPassword1 -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
```

I can connect it via the **powershell** and via the **Sql server management studio** (localhost, 1433 and SA and MyPass1)
So I can see the databases and play with them.

However in .NET core API application I cannot connect to the dockerized mssql server express (windows dockerized and not linux)

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=master;User=sa;Password=MyPassword1 ;"
  },
```

Unfortunately I get this sql exception always:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.)'

So the mssql-server-windows-express container is running I can reach it by the powershell command and by the sql server management studio, but when I run the .net core api applicaion in the visual studio 2017 I get this sql exception always.

Comment: You should be able to use `docker.for.win.localhost` as the host.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost in terms of your computer is not the same as localhost in terms of the running Docker instance. By using 127.0.0.1, you're telling it to connect to itself, not your local machine. You need to change this to your local machine's *actual* IP.

Comment: I will try this. But I still not get why the SQL Server Management Studio could connect to the Docker instance by using 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Comment: Because that is your computer talking to your computer (via the tunnel into the container over 1433). Inside a container localhost is that container, not your computer.

Comment: Well, I tried, the `docker ps --all` said the sql server docker instance has the `0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp` and tried with 0.0.0.0:1433 in connection string but still not works. (interesting for me if I use the windows container by Docker for Windows, I do not see any ip address of docker)

Comment: That's not the IPs. It's showing the port bindings. 0.0.0.0 means all IPs that are assigned. You need to use the IP address of you computer (i.e run ipconfig). This is all very basic network stuff that really has nothing to do with Docker.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried before those ips, the 10.0.75.1, (DockerNat) the 192.168.0.23 which was in the system32/driver/etc/hosts file that ip address was assigned to the host.docker.internal domain. I turn off the firewall and still nothing... I think this is a bad way, because the non asp.net core apps works fine with docker (I mean laravel php and others)

Comment: I seriously don't know how to say it any clearer: use the IP address assigned to your machine. You're trying everything but.